# Error opening scene builder

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm making a program with Javafx Eclipse and I get an error when I open the program with the Scene Builder

This is the error:

```
Opening the file with SceneBuilder failed. 
Try setting the absolute path to scenebuilder in your preferences
```

Answer (score 44):

Set the SceneBuilder executable path in the JavaFX of your Eclipse IDE as the following:

1. Window -> Preferences -> JavaFX
2. Click "Browse" and navigate to the JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0 bash file (linux) or JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0.exe (windows) like the following:

   Windows: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0`

   Linux: `/opt/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0`

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you are running the latest version of Eclipse. I've tested this with Luna 4.4 as I had the same issue.

Install the latest version of JavaFX Scene Builder. You can find version 2.0 here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html

**Then set your absolute path to the JavaFX Scene Builder in your preferences:**

1. Click on the menu path: Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Association
2. Select *.fxml in the "File types:" list on the right hand side
3. Click the "Add..." button for the "Associated editors:" list.
4. Click the "External programs" in the "Editor Selection" menu.
5. Click the "External programs" radio button.
6. Click the "Browse..." button and Navigate to this path: "C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0".
   Select the file: JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe
7. Click the "Open" button.

In the Editor Selection window select the "OK" button.

In the **Associated editors:** list, select "JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0" and click the "Default" button.

Now you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you, why there is no binary download from oracle anymore?

Answer (score 13):

1. I downloaded SceneBuilder 8.0 from http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/ because [Oracle only provides the source code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html).
2. Configure Eclipse to use SceneBuilder executable. Go to Preferences -> JavaFX -> set SceneBuilder executable. Mine was `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe`

Comment: Cool @Glavin001 Just what I was trying to configure. SceneBuilder 8.0 is better to work with Java 8 (JavaFX 8). Your instructions work like a charm. The Gluon SceneBuilder is a better choice for me, specially if you don't wanna build whatever the guys in oracle are shipping as SceneBuilder source code now. PS: I think SceneBuilder is not officially supported anymore for JavaFX 8 onwards.

Answer (score 10):

Java FX Scene Builder is not part of the Java SDK nor the e(fx)clipse plugin. It's an external tool that you have to download and install separatly. [Java FX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html#javafx-scenebuilder-2.0-oth-JPR) is part of the [Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html), if link doesn't work, you'll probably find a link to the Archive at the bottom of the [Java Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) page, and find it from there.

After installation, the cleanest way is to set the path under Window > Preferences > JavaFX

(on Windows, browse and select C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe as executable).

This will render the context menu option "Open with SceneBuilder" operational on *.fxml files.

Unfortunately this doesn't add SceneBuilder as an internal editor or external program, so if you want the file associations, you'll still have to browse for your external program int the file association dialog under Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations. You can choose *.fxml, and add an associated editor, choosing "External programs" and browsing for the above mentionned executable.

Answer (score 2):

set the path to SceneBuilder app; to do this on mac os

1. go to eclipse in your menu bar and click on preferences or press the keyboard shortcut "cmd" + ",".
2. then click on JavaFX
3. click on browse to select the path to sceneBuilder executable (which should be in your application folder if you are running mac os.

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous answers solve the described problem for me.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29025013/3992939) did.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading javafx scene builder from the link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html

Then integrate it with your ide by Window>preferences and add a file adssociation as an external program to it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error: [image: SceneBuilderError]

The way I solved it is by me going to (on Mac) Eclipse/Preferences/JavaFX
[image: JavaFX Preferences]
SceneBuilder executable, click on "Browse" then select the application SceneBuilder. 
that should fix it. Apply and close.
Now try it again and it should open it up. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Those of you who are using MacOS ( in my case ), Go to JavaFx from preferences then browse to application folder and select scene builder.

Doing other ways wont open the exact file you are trying to edit (It may make a new file which will be untitled and you have to save it manually on the project directory). Also right clicking the fxml file, you wont be able to use the option (open with scenebuilder).

Answer (score 0):

This could as easy as you have missed installing the [Scene Builder](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-downloads.html#javafx-scenebuilder-2.0-oth-JPR) for the JavaFx.
By installing only the JavaFx from the eclipse market is not enough you have to manuall follow that above link of scene builder and download the softare and after installation just check again it will definatelly work now!

This thing worked in my Case :)

Answer (score 0):

### For Windows users:

Although the question is asked 07 years ago, still the problem persists. Recently I get the same error in the question. I am a Windows user and I get my error fixed by a combination of methods as follows. I will explain the steps very simply that could be understood by anybody. Because this problem is often faced by newbies to JavaFX and Eclipse IDE.

1. First download and install the JavaFXSceneBuilder. Remember to copy the path where it will be installed. (mine: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0`)
   Link: [Click here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-downloads.html)
   (Sometimes this link will not work when new updates are released. Then simply google search for *'JavaFXScenBuilder download'*. Then download the latest version that suits your OS)
2. Next go to the Menu tab in Eclipse.
3. Go to Window -> Preferences
4. In the search box, Search 'JavaFX' and click on it.
   [image: Browse JavaFXSceneBuilder]
5. Then, click on the 'Browse' button in front of the 'SceneBuilder executable'.
6. Go to the path initially copied in step 01, and find the 'JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe' file (yours version may be different if install a later version).
   [image: Select .exe file]
7. Select it. Then click on 'Apply'. Next 'Apply and close'.
   [image: Apply and Close]
8. Now go back to the .fxml file and try open with 'SceneBuilder'.

Hope this answer may help for the new users of eclipse like me...!