# Using JavaFX (JDK 1.8.0_40) in Eclipse Luna does not show the SceneBuilder to create the UI

Tags: javafx

I am new to JavaFX.  When I try to build a simple JavaFX program in Eclipse Luna.
after I created the new FXML Document, I try to open the .fxml file through the scenebuilder, Eclipse shows the following message in the editor:

"opening the file with scene builder failed. Try setting the absolute path to scenebuilder in your the preferences"

Any hints how to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is setting to set the path to the Scenebuilder in Eclipse. Go to the preferences and search for the JavaFX tab.

[image: Scenebuilder Preferences]

EDIT:

The reason for not finding the scenebuilder in the jdk 8 build is that Oracle has decided to no longer provide binary downloads for it.

Have a look at these posts: [Oracle Scenebuilder JavaFX 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808130/where-exactly-can-i-download-the-latest-version-of-scene-builder-for-java)

Btw, you can find the recent builds of scenebuilder at http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/

Comment: I have checked this but, I did not see the SceneBuilder in my program files. but I have installed the new software in eclipse, please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808130/where-exactly-can-i-download-the-latest-version-of-scene-builder-for-java