# eclipse - "Open with sceenbuilder" is no where to be found

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

Having a Sample.fxml and scenebuilder executable setup correct in eclipse (neon),
I should be able to right click Sample.fxml and select "Open with sceenbuilder".
This is however not possible as "Open with sceenbuilder" is no where to be found.

Installed JRS's jdk1.8.0_74

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly** [Install](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html) e(fx)clipse + Scene Builder and it should work automatically.

> If not:

After you have done the above ..
Configure `Eclipse` to use SceneBuilder executable. Go to Preferences -> JavaFX -> set SceneBuilder executable.

For example on Windows 64 bit:

**Windows**: C:\Users\AlexanderPC\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder.exe

By default SceneBuilder executable is there.If not you have to check where it is.

For further reading check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096331/error-opening-scene-builder)

Answer (score 1):

Install [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) and everything will show up!

Answer (score 0):

The link helped.

I edited the file association, opening scenbuilder as an external editor.

It was not the answer I was looking for but it works just as good, so thanks.

Comment: install eclipse Neon along with e(fx)clipse and create a JavaFX project it will work.